# Create Categories in Wordpress PHP to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rpc, xml-rpc

I need the creation from Wordpress Categories in (.NET) from PHP converted because i only can Programm in c#

```
    <?php
        include ("IXR_Library.php");

        $log = '';
        $pwd = '';
        $xmlrpc = 'http://www..com/xmlrpc.php';

        $client = new IXR_Client($xmlrpc);

        $res = $client->query('wp.newCategory', '', $log, $pwd,
        array(
        'name' => '@MyCat000egory',
        'slug' => 'my-category-slug',
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'description' => 'Test category by xml-rpc'
        )
        );
?>
```